# Soft light blend mode not working

Tags: css, gradient, blend, linear-gradients

I am trying to apply a soft light blend mode of an image against a linear gradient but the effect is not loading on chrome. My code is:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff5858), color-stop(100%, #f857a6));
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
background-image: url('../img/mall.png'), linear-gradient(0deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff5858', endColorstr='#f857a6',GradientType=0 );
background-blend-mode: soft-light;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working ok for me :

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/800'), linear-gradient(0deg, #f857a6 0%, #ff5858 100%);
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```